# Is there a messaging system for .NET+Mono with no external dependency?

Tags: .net, mono, message-queue, messaging, servicebus

I'm looking for a simple messaging system for .NET, that run as a library with no external dependency.

The requirements are simple: I'd like to be able to call an external HTTP service, and if that service is offline or not responding for some reason, the system should queue the messages for later or discard previous and keep only the latest message, regular messaging stuff.

But I'm looking for something that:

- Runs on Mono/linux
- Free/open source
- Have no external dependency, it should run as part of the application
- Be able to work with existing JSON APIs, and not require the endpoints to be running anything specific

I don't need to receive messages, it is all request/response based. Also, I don't mind if it uses a local database to persist messages during crashes, but that is not that important.

I have looked at NServiceBus, MassTransit and some others. But all seem to require MSMQ or RabbitMQ, and also seem to require the endpoints to be running the same service.

Are there alternatives out there I should look at before thinking of rolling my own?

Thanks

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) and its .NET binding called [NetMQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:clr).

Comment: Looks promising! Someone else answered that, but deleted the answer for some reason. Anyway, ZeroMQ doesn't solve exactly the problem I have, but seems to provides a very good base for it. I'm currently looking into it to see how I can use it. It also seems to be a great library for other projects.

Comment: In the past, I tried https://github.com/Jiddler/Hyperletter.  It's free, open source, running on mono/linux, but it needs to run its own listerner

Comment: After reading a lot about ZeroMQ, it seems this is really the answer. It provides a good base for messaging without requiring any dependency. Of all the things I need, the only thing missing is using existing HTTP services, but this can be abstracted on top of existing patterns. It also has a lot of other patterns I can make use of. Thank you very much!

Comment: @hugo, I'm going with zmq, but you should put that in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I tried http://github.com/Jiddler/Hyperletter. It's free, open source, running under mono/linux, but it needs to run its own listener.  And my tests were running under Xamarin/Android.