# cross-platform ipc mechanism in .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform

I am new to Windows technologies. I want to use an IPC mechanism for high-frequency data exchanges between processes. what are some of the cross-platform IPC mechanism available in .net framework?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a great article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), describing the several possibilities of IPC.

Mostly IPC is refered to as communication between processes on the same host.

Therefor you are referring to 'cross plattform' it is dependant if you mean only the .Net Framework or also communication between .Net Framework applications and applications written in other Languages. Additionally you are mentioning that you are 'new to windows'.

When you are talking about the .Net Framework Core which is available for Windows and Linux you could eg. use Protobuffers where you can find an article [here](https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/IPC-in-net-core-using-protobuf/). This way you can use normal Network / Named Pipe for communication.

Comment: Thanks for answering. With respect to cross platform, i am running C# application under Mono in Linux. I do see named pipes supported via Mono. Are there any specific message queue IPCs also available? I found MSMQ windows dependent. Can you please suggest any widely supported message queue implementation in .net framework.

Comment: I am afraid but I do not know any native message queuing which is integrated in .net core. But perhaps this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044990/is-there-a-messaging-system-for-netmono-with-no-external-dependency) is applicable for you?